# Unable to Launch VLC Application in Debian Buster

Tags: debian, vlc, freeze, app-startup, debian-buster

I have setup debian on a newly built machine.
I have installed XFCE4 DE.

I also installed VLC but I am unable to launch it.
My environment details:
`uname -a` returns

`Linux debianNew 4.19.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.98-1 (2020-01-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`lsb_release -a` prints

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
```

`vlc -vv` prints

```
[000055f401750570] main libvlc debug: Copyright © 1996-2019 the VideoLAN team
[000055f401750570] main libvlc debug: revision 3.0.8-0-gf350b6b5a7
[000055f401750570] main libvlc debug: configured with ./configure  '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--prefix=/usr' '--includedir=${prefix}/include' '--mandir=${prefix}/share/man' '--infodir=${prefix}/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var' '--disable-silent-rules' '--libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--runstatedir=/run' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--disable-debug' '--config-cache' '--disable-update-check' '--enable-fast-install' '--docdir=/usr/share/doc/vlc' '--with-binary-version=3.0.8-0+deb10u1' '--enable-a52' '--enable-aa' '--enable-aom' '--enable-aribsub' '--enable-avahi' '--enable-bluray' '--enable-caca' '--enable-chromaprint' '--enable-chromecast' '--enable-dbus' '--enable-dca' '--enable-dvbpsi' '--enable-dvdnav' '--enable-faad' '--enable-flac' '--enable-fluidsynth' '--enable-freetype' '--enable-fribidi' '--enable-gles2' '--enable-gnutls' '--enable-harfbuzz' '--enable-jack' '--enable-kate' '--enable-libass' '--enable-libmpeg2' '--enable-libxml2' '--enable-lirc' '--enable-live555' '--enable-mad' '--enable-matroska' '--enable-mod' '--enable-mpc' '--enable-mpg123' '--enable-mtp' '--enable-ncurses' '--enable-notify' '--enable-ogg' '--enable-opus' '--enable-pulse' '--enable-qt' '--enable-realrtsp' '--enable-samplerate' '--enable-sdl-image' '--enable-sftp' '--enable-shine' '--enable-shout' '--enable-skins2' '--enable-sndio' '--enable-soxr' '--enable-spatialaudio' '--enable-speex' '--enable-svg' '--enable-svgdec' '--enable-taglib' '--enable-theora' '--enable-twolame' '--enable-upnp' '--enable-vdpau' '--enable-vnc' '--enable-vorbis' '--enable-x264' '--enable-x265' '--enable-zvbi' '--with-kde-solid=/usr/share/solid/actions/' '--disable-d3d11va' '--disable-decklink' '--disable-directx' '--disable-dsm' '--disable-dxva2' '--disable-fdkaac' '--disable-fluidlite' '--disable-freerdp' '--disable-goom' '--disable-gst-decode' '--disable-libtar' '--disable-macosx' '--disable-macosx-avfoundation' '--disable-macosx-qtkit' '--disable-mfx' '--disable-opencv' '--disable-projectm' '--disable-schroedinger' '--disable-sparkle' '--disable-srt' '--disable-telx' '--disable-vpx' '--disable-vsxu' '--disable-wasapi' '--enable-alsa' '--enable-dc1394' '--enable-dv1394' '--enable-libplacebo' '--enable-linsys' '--enable-nfs' '--enable-omxil' '--enable-udev' '--enable-v4l2' '--enable-wayland' '--enable-libva' '--enable-vcd' '--enable-smbclient' '--disable-oss' '--enable-crystalhd' '--enable-mmx' '--enable-sse' '--disable-neon' '--disable-altivec' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vlc-3CK1JH/vlc-3.0.8=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security ' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vlc-3CK1JH/vlc-3.0.8=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security ' 'OBJCFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vlc-3CK1JH/vlc-3.0.8=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security'
[000055f401750570] main libvlc debug: searching plug-in modules
[000055f401750570] main libvlc debug: loading plugins cache file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat
[000055f401750570] main libvlc debug: recursively browsing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/plugins'
[000055f401750570] main libvlc debug: plug-ins loaded: 523 modules
[000055f401750570] main libvlc debug: opening config file (/home/adam/.config/vlc/vlcrc)
[000055f4017508c0] main logger debug: looking for logger module matching "any": 4 candidates
[000055f4017508c0] main logger debug: using logger module "console"
[000055f401750570] main libvlc debug: translation test: code is "C"
[000055f4017e5ee0] main keystore debug: looking for keystore module matching "memory": 4 candidates
[000055f4017e5ee0] main keystore debug: using keystore module "memory"
[000055f401750570] main libvlc debug: CPU has capabilities MMX MMXEXT SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FPU 
[000055f4017f08f0] main input debug: Creating an input for 'Media Library'
[000055f4017f08f0] main input debug: Input is a meta file: disabling unneeded options
[000055f4017f08f0] main input debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
[000055f4017f08f0] main input debug: using default timeshift path
[000055f4017f08f0] main input debug: `file/directory:///home/adam/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' gives access `file' demux `directory' path `/home/adam/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[000055f4017eff00] main input source debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='directory' location='/home/adam/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' file='/home/adam/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[000055f4017f0520] main demux debug: looking for access_demux module matching "file": 17 candidates
[000055f4017f0520] main demux debug: no access_demux modules matched
[000055f40180f9e0] main stream debug: creating access: file:///home/adam/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf
[000055f40180f9e0] main stream debug:  (path: /home/adam/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf)
[000055f40180f9e0] main stream debug: looking for access module matching "file": 28 candidates
[000055f40180f9e0] main stream debug: using access module "filesystem"
[000055f401810aa0] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "prefetch,cache_read": 26 candidates
[000055f401810aa0] cache_read stream debug: Using stream method for AStream*
[000055f401810aa0] cache_read stream debug: starting pre-buffering
[000055f401810aa0] cache_read stream debug: received first data after 0 ms
[000055f401810aa0] cache_read stream debug: pre-buffering done 296 bytes in 0s - 13764 KiB/s
[000055f401810aa0] main stream debug: using stream_filter module "cache_read"
[000055f401811b50] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 26 candidates
[000055f401811b50] playlist stream debug: using XSPF playlist reader
[000055f401811b50] main stream debug: using stream_filter module "playlist"
[000055f401811b50] main stream debug: stream filter added to 0x55f401810aa0
[000055f401815080] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 26 candidates
[000055f401815080] main stream debug: no stream_filter modules matched
[000055f4017e62f0] main stream_directory debug: looking for stream_directory module matching "any": 1 candidates
[000055f4017e62f0] main stream_directory debug: no stream_directory modules matched
[000055f4017eff00] main input source debug: attachment of directory-extractor failed for file:///home/adam/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf
[000055f401815080] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "record": 26 candidates
[000055f401815080] main stream debug: using stream_filter module "record"
[000055f4017eff00] main input source debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='directory' location='/home/adam/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' file='/home/adam/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[000055f4017f0520] main demux debug: looking for demux module matching "directory": 55 candidates
[000055f4017f0520] main demux debug: using demux module "directory"
[000055f401819c50] main demux meta debug: looking for meta reader module matching "any": 2 candidates
[000055f401819c50] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/adam/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[000055f401819c50] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[000055f401819c50] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/reader/filename.luac
[000055f401819c50] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[000055f401819c50] main demux meta debug: no meta reader modules matched
[000055f4017f08f0] main input debug: `file/directory:///home/adam/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' successfully opened
[000055f40181f510] main xml reader debug: looking for xml reader module matching "any": 1 candidates
[000055f40181f510] main xml reader debug: using xml reader module "xml"
[000055f4017f08f0] main input debug: EOF reached
[000055f4017f0520] main demux debug: removing module "directory"
[000055f401815080] main stream debug: removing module "record"
[000055f401811b50] main stream debug: removing module "playlist"
[000055f401810aa0] main stream debug: removing module "cache_read"
[000055f40180f9e0] main stream debug: removing module "filesystem"
[000055f4017544e0] main playlist debug: creating audio output
[000055f40181f640] main audio output debug: looking for audio output module matching "any": 6 candidates
[000055f40181f640] vlcpulse audio output debug: using library version 12.2.0
[000055f40181f640] vlcpulse audio output debug:  (compiled with version 12.2.0, protocol 32)
[000055f40181f640] vlcpulse audio output debug: connected locally to unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native as client #29
[000055f40181f640] vlcpulse audio output debug: using protocol 32, server protocol 32
[000055f40181f640] pulse audio output debug: adding sink 0: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo (Built-in Audio Analog Stereo)
[000055f40181f640] main audio output debug: using audio output module "pulse"
[000055f4017544e0] main playlist debug: keeping audio output
[000055f40182e410] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "dbus,none": 19 candidates
[000055f40182e410] dbus interface debug: listening on dbus as: org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc
[000055f40182e410] main interface debug: using interface module "dbus"
[000055f401832310] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "hotkeys,none": 19 candidates
[000055f401832310] main interface debug: using interface module "hotkeys"
[000055f401832ca0] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "globalhotkeys,none": 19 candidates
[000055f40182e410] dbus interface debug: Getting All properties
[000055f401832ca0] main interface debug: using interface module "xcb_hotkeys"
[000055f401750570] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[000055f401833fc0] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "any": 19 candidates
[000055f40182e410] dbus interface debug: Getting All properties
[000055f40182e410] dbus interface debug: Getting All properties
[000055f401833fc0] qt interface debug: Boring first Run Wizard
Gdk-Message: 17:16:09.303: vlc: Fatal IO error 0 (Success) on X server :0.0.
```

`vlc-wrapper` prints

```
VLC media player 3.0.8 Vetinari (revision 3.0.8-0-gf350b6b5a7)
[000055ef9a300570] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Gdk-Message: 17:27:36.878: vlc: Fatal IO error 0 (Success) on X server :0.0.
```

`cvlc -vv` prints following and does nothing. It just waits there.

```
VLC media player 3.0.8 Vetinari (revision 3.0.8-0-gf350b6b5a7)
[000055d3cc8ba570] main libvlc debug: VLC media player - 3.0.8 Vetinari
[000055d3cc8ba570] main libvlc debug: Copyright © 1996-2019 the VideoLAN team
[000055d3cc8ba570] main libvlc debug: revision 3.0.8-0-gf350b6b5a7
[000055d3cc8ba570] main libvlc debug: configured with ./configure  '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--prefix=/usr' '--includedir=${prefix}/include' '--mandir=${prefix}/share/man' '--infodir=${prefix}/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var' '--disable-silent-rules' '--libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--runstatedir=/run' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--disable-debug' '--config-cache' '--disable-update-check' '--enable-fast-install' '--docdir=/usr/share/doc/vlc' '--with-binary-version=3.0.8-0+deb10u1' '--enable-a52' '--enable-aa' '--enable-aom' '--enable-aribsub' '--enable-avahi' '--enable-bluray' '--enable-caca' '--enable-chromaprint' '--enable-chromecast' '--enable-dbus' '--enable-dca' '--enable-dvbpsi' '--enable-dvdnav' '--enable-faad' '--enable-flac' '--enable-fluidsynth' '--enable-freetype' '--enable-fribidi' '--enable-gles2' '--enable-gnutls' '--enable-harfbuzz' '--enable-jack' '--enable-kate' '--enable-libass' '--enable-libmpeg2' '--enable-libxml2' '--enable-lirc' '--enable-live555' '--enable-mad' '--enable-matroska' '--enable-mod' '--enable-mpc' '--enable-mpg123' '--enable-mtp' '--enable-ncurses' '--enable-notify' '--enable-ogg' '--enable-opus' '--enable-pulse' '--enable-qt' '--enable-realrtsp' '--enable-samplerate' '--enable-sdl-image' '--enable-sftp' '--enable-shine' '--enable-shout' '--enable-skins2' '--enable-sndio' '--enable-soxr' '--enable-spatialaudio' '--enable-speex' '--enable-svg' '--enable-svgdec' '--enable-taglib' '--enable-theora' '--enable-twolame' '--enable-upnp' '--enable-vdpau' '--enable-vnc' '--enable-vorbis' '--enable-x264' '--enable-x265' '--enable-zvbi' '--with-kde-solid=/usr/share/solid/actions/' '--disable-d3d11va' '--disable-decklink' '--disable-directx' '--disable-dsm' '--disable-dxva2' '--disable-fdkaac' '--disable-fluidlite' '--disable-freerdp' '--disable-goom' '--disable-gst-decode' '--disable-libtar' '--disable-macosx' '--disable-macosx-avfoundation' '--disable-macosx-qtkit' '--disable-mfx' '--disable-opencv' '--disable-projectm' '--disable-schroedinger' '--disable-sparkle' '--disable-srt' '--disable-telx' '--disable-vpx' '--disable-vsxu' '--disable-wasapi' '--enable-alsa' '--enable-dc1394' '--enable-dv1394' '--enable-libplacebo' '--enable-linsys' '--enable-nfs' '--enable-omxil' '--enable-udev' '--enable-v4l2' '--enable-wayland' '--enable-libva' '--enable-vcd' '--enable-smbclient' '--disable-oss' '--enable-crystalhd' '--enable-mmx' '--enable-sse' '--disable-neon' '--disable-altivec' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vlc-3CK1JH/vlc-3.0.8=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security ' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vlc-3CK1JH/vlc-3.0.8=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security ' 'OBJCFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vlc-3CK1JH/vlc-3.0.8=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security'
[000055d3cc8ba570] main libvlc debug: searching plug-in modules
[000055d3cc8ba570] main libvlc debug: loading plugins cache file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat
[000055d3cc8ba570] main libvlc debug: recursively browsing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/plugins'
[000055d3cc8ba570] main libvlc debug: plug-ins loaded: 523 modules
[000055d3cc8ba570] main libvlc debug: opening config file (/home/adam/.config/vlc/vlcrc)
[000055d3cc8ba8c0] main logger debug: looking for logger module matching "any": 4 candidates
[000055d3cc8ba8c0] main logger debug: using logger module "console"
[000055d3cc8ba570] main libvlc debug: translation test: code is "C"
[000055d3cc94ff90] main keystore debug: looking for keystore module matching "memory": 4 candidates
[000055d3cc94ff90] main keystore debug: using keystore module "memory"
[000055d3cc8ba570] main libvlc debug: CPU has capabilities MMX MMXEXT SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FPU 
[000055d3cc95a9a0] main input debug: Creating an input for 'Media Library'
[000055d3cc95a9a0] main input debug: Input is a meta file: disabling unneeded options
[000055d3cc95a9a0] main input debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
[000055d3cc95a9a0] main input debug: using default timeshift path
[000055d3cc95a9a0] main input debug: `file/directory:///home/adam/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' gives access `file' demux `directory' path `/home/adam/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[000055d3cc959fb0] main input source debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='directory' location='/home/adam/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' file='/home/adam/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[000055d3cc95a5d0] main demux debug: looking for access_demux module matching "file": 17 candidates
[000055d3cc95a5d0] main demux debug: no access_demux modules matched
[000055d3cc979a90] main stream debug: creating access: file:///home/adam/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf
[000055d3cc979a90] main stream debug:  (path: /home/adam/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf)
[000055d3cc979a90] main stream debug: looking for access module matching "file": 28 candidates
[000055d3cc979a90] main stream debug: using access module "filesystem"
[000055d3cc97ab50] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "prefetch,cache_read": 26 candidates
[000055d3cc97ab50] cache_read stream debug: Using stream method for AStream*
[000055d3cc97ab50] cache_read stream debug: starting pre-buffering
[000055d3cc97ab50] cache_read stream debug: received first data after 0 ms
[000055d3cc97ab50] cache_read stream debug: pre-buffering done 296 bytes in 0s - 3482 KiB/s
[000055d3cc97ab50] main stream debug: using stream_filter module "cache_read"
[000055d3cc97bc00] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 26 candidates
[000055d3cc97bc00] playlist stream debug: using XSPF playlist reader
[000055d3cc97bc00] main stream debug: using stream_filter module "playlist"
[000055d3cc97bc00] main stream debug: stream filter added to 0x55d3cc97ab50
[000055d3cc97f130] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 26 candidates
[000055d3cc97f130] main stream debug: no stream_filter modules matched
[000055d3cc9503a0] main stream_directory debug: looking for stream_directory module matching "any": 1 candidates
[000055d3cc9503a0] main stream_directory debug: no stream_directory modules matched
[000055d3cc959fb0] main input source debug: attachment of directory-extractor failed for file:///home/adam/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf
[000055d3cc97f130] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "record": 26 candidates
[000055d3cc97f130] main stream debug: using stream_filter module "record"
[000055d3cc959fb0] main input source debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='directory' location='/home/adam/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' file='/home/adam/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[000055d3cc95a5d0] main demux debug: looking for demux module matching "directory": 55 candidates
[000055d3cc95a5d0] main demux debug: using demux module "directory"
[000055d3cc983d00] main demux meta debug: looking for meta reader module matching "any": 2 candidates
[000055d3cc983d00] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/adam/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[000055d3cc983d00] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[000055d3cc983d00] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/reader/filename.luac
[000055d3cc983d00] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[000055d3cc983d00] main demux meta debug: no meta reader modules matched
[000055d3cc95a9a0] main input debug: `file/directory:///home/adam/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' successfully opened
[000055d3cc98f7b0] main xml reader debug: looking for xml reader module matching "any": 1 candidates
[000055d3cc98f7b0] main xml reader debug: using xml reader module "xml"
[000055d3cc95a9a0] main input debug: EOF reached
[000055d3cc95a5d0] main demux debug: removing module "directory"
[000055d3cc97f130] main stream debug: removing module "record"
[000055d3cc97bc00] main stream debug: removing module "playlist"
[000055d3cc97ab50] main stream debug: removing module "cache_read"
[000055d3cc979a90] main stream debug: removing module "filesystem"
[000055d3cc8be4e0] main playlist debug: creating audio output
[000055d3cc98f3f0] main audio output debug: looking for audio output module matching "any": 6 candidates
[000055d3cc98f3f0] vlcpulse audio output debug: using library version 12.2.0
[000055d3cc98f3f0] vlcpulse audio output debug:  (compiled with version 12.2.0, protocol 32)
[000055d3cc98f3f0] vlcpulse audio output debug: connected locally to unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native as client #32
[000055d3cc98f3f0] vlcpulse audio output debug: using protocol 32, server protocol 32
[000055d3cc98f3f0] pulse audio output debug: adding sink 0: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo (Built-in Audio Analog Stereo)
[000055d3cc98f3f0] main audio output debug: using audio output module "pulse"
[000055d3cc8be4e0] main playlist debug: keeping audio output
[000055d3cc998410] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "dbus,none": 19 candidates
[000055d3cc998410] dbus interface debug: listening on dbus as: org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc
[000055d3cc998410] main interface debug: using interface module "dbus"
[000055d3cc99c2e0] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "hotkeys,none": 19 candidates
[000055d3cc99c2e0] main interface debug: using interface module "hotkeys"
[000055d3cc99cc70] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "globalhotkeys,none": 19 candidates
[000055d3cc998410] dbus interface debug: Getting All properties
[000055d3cc99cc70] main interface debug: using interface module "xcb_hotkeys"
[000055d3cc99df90] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "dummy": 19 candidates
[000055d3cc998410] dbus interface debug: Getting All properties
[000055d3cc99df90] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[000055d3cc99df90] main interface debug: using interface module "dummy"
[000055d3cc8be4e0] main playlist: playlist is empty
[000055d3cc8be4e0] main playlist debug: nothing to play
[000055d3cc998410] dbus interface debug: Getting All properties
```

I tried re-installing VLC, `apt-get update` `apt-get upgrade`. Nothing has worked so far.

Any fixes, suggestions, links, references, etc. will be of great help.

Thanks in advance!